# How to log changes in two elements on a HTML?

Tags: javascript, logging

I've got a webpage which changes every time I click on a button. I'd like to log automatically to my desktop's `log.txt`, in such a way that all events are logged by tag. I believe this is possible with JavaScript, since all the changes are done thanks to JS.

Thanks for any reply in advance.

Comment: `log automatically to my desktop` - no, a web page, fortunately, has no direct access to the underlying operating system and files within it

Comment: Use Web Storage built into browsers or a remote cloud storage service. This whole question is far too broad as outlined by guidelines in the [help]

Comment: Jaromanda X Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: charlietfl any script that you would recommend?